# Animate Views form one point to another point Android programatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, animation, android-animation

Im trying to animate two Buttons from a point (1st button). On Click of the first button, that button is set to INVISIBLE/GONE and two other button are shown. I am trying to pass the X and Y values of the View(1st button) as follows:

```
button.getX();
button.getY();
```

but im not getting the exact center (of 1st button).

Im trying to send those X and Y values to the animation but both the buttons (button2, button3) are coming side by side.. I want them to overlap as the point where they start animation is same. Im using the following code for the animation:

```
AnimatorSet animations = new AnimatorSet();

Animator xAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(button, "translationX", finalXValue);
xAnim.setDuration(3000);

Animator yAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(button, "translationY", finalYValue);
yAnim.setDuration(3000);

Animator alphaAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(button, "alpha", finalAlphaValue);
alphaAnim.setDuration(alphaDuration);

//Play all the animations together
animations.play(xAnim).with(yAnim).with(alphaAnim);
```

I want the animation to be like this

[image]

Comment: "getX" and "getY" doesn't give the center.  It gives the left and top coordinate of the view respectively.  To get the center you need to do `getX + half_view_width` and `getY + half_view_height` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

@Deev Thanks thats really helped but the code im using has no start position

```
TranslateAnimation tanim_stay = new TranslateAnimation(
            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, getIntent().getFloatExtra("ButtonX", 0) - btn_armed_stay.getWidth(),
            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, btn_armed_stay.getX()+ (btn_armed_stay.getWidth()/2),
            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, -getIntent().getFloatExtra("ButtonY", 0),
            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, btn_armed_stay.getY()+ (btn_armed_stay.getHeight()/2));
```

Im using this code for the start and end position of the animation but how to add another animation to the current Translate animation.. I want to add Alpha animation to this Translate animation..